# No error, but data doesn't get inserted into table

Tags: java, postgresql

In my database I have two tables called car and ad. In car i have a foreign key referencing the adId value in ad. When i run my code, i don't get any errors, but data is only inserted into ad, not car. Any suggestions? Here's my code:

```
public void createAd(Ad ad, Car car) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        if (con != null) {
            ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"ad\"(\"title\", \"description\", \"author\", \"image\") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            ps.setString(1, ad.getTitle());
            ps.setString(2, ad.getDescription());
            ps.setString(3, ad.getAuthor());
            ps.setBytes(4, ad.getImage());
            ps.executeQuery();

            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT currval('\"ad_adId_seq\"');");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            int adId = rs.getInt("currval");
            ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"ad\"(\"adId\") VALUES (?);");
            ps.setInt(1, adId);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ad.setAdId(adId);

            ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"car\"(\"distanceTraveled\", \"age\", \"condition\", \"vin\", \"brand\", \"price\", \"ad_adId\") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            ps.setInt(1, car.getDistanceTraveled());
            ps.setInt(2, car.getAge());
            ps.setString(3, car.getCondition());
            ps.setString(4, car.getVIN());
            ps.setString(5, car.getBrand());
            ps.setInt(6, car.getPrice());
            ps.setInt(6, adId);
            ps.executeQuery();
            car.setAdId(adId);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you're using `ps.executeQuery()` for the insert into car.  Try `ps.executeUpdate()`

Comment: Probably your `con` object is null. Please show the code where you are initializing the connection `con` object too.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your last query :

```
ps.setInt(7, adId);
```

instead of

```
ps.setInt(6, adId);
```

Comment: Omg, i feel so dumb. Sometimes i guess you just need a pair of fresh eyes to take a look. I think it should do the trick, will try it out later. Thank you!

Comment: No issues, you should probably see about spring, MVC and using beans. Those are the standard ways for CRUD operations as well as for any application (Enterprise especially). Happy coding !!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should take a look at [spring-database](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html). Using [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate) will reduce a lot of the `JDBC` boiler plate code and more important will take care for a lot of jdbc connection leaks worries for you.

If you sill need to use plain `JDBC`, you need to properly initialize the connection object and use `update` instead of `query`, when using update statements.

Also you need to properly close the `statement` objects that were created. 
You should do something similar to the below code:

```
Connection con = null;
PrepareStatement ps1 = null;
PrepareStatement ps2 = null;
PrepareStatement ps3 = null;
PrepareStatement ps4 = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dbName";
String user = "userName";
String password = "userPass";

try {
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
  ps1 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"ad\"(\"title\", \"description\", \"author\", \"image\") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
  ps1.setString(1, ad.getTitle());
  ps1.setString(2, ad.getDescription());
  ps1.setString(3, ad.getAuthor());
  ps1.setBytes(4, ad.getImage());
  ps1.executeUpdate();

  ps2 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT currval('\"ad_adId_seq\"');");
  rs = ps2.executeQuery();
  if(rs.next())
   int adId = rs.getInt("currval");
  }
  ps3 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"ad\"(\"adId\") VALUES (?);");
  ps3.setInt(1, adId);
  ps3.executeUpdate();
  ad.setAdId(adId);

  ps4 = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"car\"(\"distanceTraveled\", \"age\", \"condition\", \"vin\", \"brand\", \"price\", \"ad_adId\") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  ps4.setInt(1, car.getDistanceTraveled());
  ps4.setInt(2, car.getAge());
  ps4.setString(3, car.getCondition());
  ps4.setString(4, car.getVIN());
  ps4.setString(5, car.getBrand());
  ps4.setInt(6, car.getPrice());
  ps4.setInt(7, adId);
  ps4.executeUpdate();
  car.setAdId(adId);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
   Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
   lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to execute updates", ex);
} finally {
   try {
     if (rs != null)
         rs.close();
      if (ps1 != null)
         ps1.close();
      if (ps2 != null) 
         ps2.close();
      if (ps3 != null) 
         ps3.close();
      if (ps4 != null)
         ps4.close();
      if (con != null)
         con.close();
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
       Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
       lgr.log(Level.WARNING, "Unable to close the connection", ex);
   }
}
```